# SQL concatenations

Tags: sql, ms-access

Say I have

```
SELECT [id] as [Customer's ID] FROM [users];
```

How how can I put a string in front of [id] value?

I've tried

```
SELECT + "CTMR-ID-" + [id] as [Customer's ID]
```

but it don't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a unnecessary `+` after `SELECT` keyword

Try this way, Given `ID` is of `Varchar` type else you may have to cast the ID explicitly to `Varchar`

```
SELECT  "CTMR-ID-" & [id] as [Customer's ID]
```

`&` will avoid `NULL` values. Even when `ID` is `NULL` you will get `CTMR-ID-` in result

```
SELECT  "CTMR-ID-" + [id] as [Customer's ID]
```

`+` will consider `NULL` values. When `ID` is `NULL` the result of concatenation will be `NULL`

Comment: Thank you sir. I've first seen + operator used when I discovered AS and I've never thought of &.

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively you can use `CONCAT` function if you are using SQL Server (starting with 2008).

```
SELECT CONCAT ( 'CTMR-ID-', id) AS [Customer's ID] 
FROM [users];
```

Comment: First question is not tagged with **Sql Server**. Next `CONCAT` is introduced in **Sql Server 2012**. Before answering you need to check the TAG's present below the question.